# How to query and count based on the status of the entry from the database?

Tags: php, html, sql, laravel

I have a table named `Patents`. The table values are:

```
 id | person_id | status | date_submitted | date_approved
```

The `person_id`(fk from persons table) contains the `id` of the person who created the patent. Status has 2 values which are 1(pending) or 2(approved). The problem i have right now is i can't count both the patents that were approved and the total patents of the person who created the patents.

**Controller** file

```
$start = $request->input('start');
$end = $request->input('end');
$approvedPatents = DB::table('patents')
    ->select('person_id', DB::raw('count(*) as CountofApprovedPatents, status'))
    ->where([
        ['status', '=', 2],
        ['date_approved', '>=', $start],
        ['date_approved', '<=', $end],
    ])
    ->groupBy('person_id')
    ->orderBy('status', 'desc')
    ->get();

$totalPatents = DB::table('patents')
    ->select('person_id', DB::raw('count(*) as CountofPatents'))
    ->where([
        ['date_approved', '>=', $start],
        ['date_approved', '<=', $end],
    ])
    ->groupBy('person_id')
    ->orderBy('status', 'desc')
    ->get();  

$patents = $approvedPatents->merge($totalPatents);
$results = $patents->all();  
return view('admin.patents.showPatents', compact('results', 
'start', 'end'));
```

**Blade view**

```
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>Person ID</th>
        <th>Patents Approved</th>
        <th>Total Patents</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    @foreach($results as $result)
      <tr>
        <td>{{ $result->person_id }} </td>
        <td>{{ $result->CountofApprovedPatents }} </td> //Error
        <td>{{ $result->CountofPatents }} </td> //Error
     </tr>
    @endforeach  
 </tbody>
```

I can display the `$patent->CountofApprovedPatents` but not the other select. I really need help, i have no idea how to get the CountofPatents because i have 2 separate selects. I tried doing a foreach for each of the variable but it displays double results instead of being compiled in one row. The `$start` and `$end` variables are just dates to determine patents between those 2 dates.

Answer (score 0):

I can see that you have 2 queries in your controller, each generating a collection.

Then in your blade file, you are looping over one collection (not two).

You probably need to look in your controller below where you provided the snippet at the logic used to join these data sets.

Try using dd($myCollection) at different points of the logic, to view your data, before pushing it to the controller to ensure you are getting what you expect.

===============================================

EDIT... I have included some code here..  this should give you what you need.
There may be a better way of doing it with collections, and I am not sure how this would scale with big quantities of records.
This should get you running for now.

```
//setup test
$approvedPatents = collect([
    ['name'=>'andy', 'count'=> 1],
    ['name'=>'joe', 'count'=> 2],
    ['name'=>'william', 'count'=> 5],
]);
$allPatents = collect([
    ['name'=>'andy', 'count'=> 11],
    ['name'=>'joe', 'count'=> 12],
    ['name'=>'william', 'count'=> 15],
]);

//combine collections - basically scan the allpatents collection and get the count from the matching currentpatents collection, and create a new collection entry with both in the combinedpatents collection
$combined = collect();
foreach ($allPatents as $patent) {
    $approvedPatentCount = ($approvedPatents->where('name',$patent['name'])->first())['count'];
    $combined->push([
        'name'=>$patent['name'],
        'allPatentsCount'=>$patent['count'],
        'approvedPatentsCount'=>$approvedPatentCount,
    ]);
}

//display results
foreach ($combined as $c) {
    dump($c);
}

// results from browser
array:3 [▼
  "name" => "andy"
  "allPatentsCount" => 11
  "approvedPatentsCount" => 1
]
array:3 [▼
  "name" => "joe"
  "allPatentsCount" => 12
  "approvedPatentsCount" => 2
]
array:3 [▼
  "name" => "william"
  "allPatentsCount" => 15
  "approvedPatentsCount" => 5
]
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I can query both of them correctly but only by doing it separately. I tried adding a foreach on top of the foreach i provided above which is foreach($totalPatents as $total patent) <td>{{$totalPatent->CountofPatents}}</td>. I got the correct data but it make another table instead of being under the <td> of the $approvedPatents foreach

Comment: Can you include the code further down in our controller (where you merge the two collections)?  and where you call the view.  I think your issue might be in that code.

Comment: I edited the code, i included the merge(). I tried to dd($results) and i got the CountofApprovedPatents and CountOfPatents values. But i have trouble accessing it. I tried to do {{$results->CountofApprovedPatents}} but it returns as undefined. How does it work? This is the first time i used merge().

Comment: I tried the code, i get the 'Cannot use object of type stdClass as array' at this part /$approvedPatentCount = ($approvedPatents->where('name',$patent['name'])->first())['count'];/

Comment: Your inputs may not have the same format as my examples.  You may need to adjust the my example to match your inputs, or you can do a dump() on your 2 collections and post a few sample from each collection, and I can check it out.

Comment: sorry for the very late reply. Here's the data //object(Illuminate\Support\Collection)#1189 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(2) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#1117 (3) { ["person_id"]=> string(10) "B123123123" ["CountofApprovedPatents"]=> int(4) ["status"]=> int(2) } [1]=> object(stdClass)#1118 (3) { ["person_id"]=> string(9) "B13212312" ["CountofApprovedPatents"]=> int(2) ["status"]=> int(2) } } }

Comment: Hey Andy, I am not sure that I understand the structure of that data.  The person_id's do not match, and there is no CountOfAllPatents field.  I can try to assist you further, but we may need to do some pair programming for a few minutes.  If you are interested, follow me on twitter, and send me a DM there.  My twitter handle is jandybain.

Comment: Don't worry. It already got solved, i made another post to make my point a little clearer. Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using laravel, you can use something like this:

```
$zzzz = Model::count();
```

then on your blade you just call

```
{{$zzzz}}
```

Comment: Thank you for the reply. But i also tried that, it returns the total count of all the patents and not the total count of the patents associated with the person_id.